# Cannot start Netbeans 8.0.1 after JAX-RPC Web Services plugin installation

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-rpc

I have a problem with Netbeans. I have installed the JAX-RPC Web Services from http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

But, after restart the IDE when the plugin is installed, Netbeans don't start newly.

The message log of Netbeans shows the following text:

```
>Log Session: Wednesday, December 3, 2014 10:36:59 AM CST
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build nbms-and-javadoc-2405-on-20141202) (#6523d6792981)
  Operating System        = Windows 8 version 6.2 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_67; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.65-b04; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_67-b01
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre
  System Locale; Encoding = es_SV (nb); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\Ghost
  Current Directory       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4
  User Directory          = C:\Users\Ghost\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4
  Cache Directory         = C:\Users\Ghost\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.openide.util.lookup.MetaInfServicesLookup]: Cannot create class org.netbeans.core.startup.NbRepository
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.SystemFileSystem.setHidden(Z)V
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.SystemFileSystem.<init>(SystemFileSystem.java:121)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.SystemFileSystem.create(SystemFileSystem.java:257)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.SessionManager.create(SessionManager.java:99)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbRepository.createDefaultFileSystem(NbRepository.java:155)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbRepository.<init>(NbRepository.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.SharedClassObjectBridge.newInstance(SharedClassObjectBridge.java:64)
[catch] at org.openide.util.lookup.MetaInfServicesLookup$Item.getInstance(MetaInfServicesLookup.java:516)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.lookup(AbstractLookup.java:422)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.ProxyLookup.lookup(ProxyLookup.java:222)
    at org.openide.filesystems.Repository.getDefault(Repository.java:362)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.getConfigFile(FileUtil.java:2109)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.getConfigRoot(FileUtil.java:2139)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:170)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openide.filesystems.Repository$MainFS cannot be cast to org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.SystemFileSystem
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.layers.ModuleLayeredFileSystem.getUserModuleLayer(ModuleLayeredFileSystem.java:219)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadLayers(NbInstaller.java:580)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadImpl(NbInstaller.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.access$000(NbInstaller.java:105)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller$1.run(NbInstaller.java:346)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil$2.run(FileUtil.java:444)
    at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:127)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:499)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(FileUtil.java:428)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.runAtomicAction(FileUtil.java:448)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.load(NbInstaller.java:343)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1194)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1017)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone know how to solve this error?
I need to use this plugin because it requires a project that I have been assigned at work.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any progress on that?

Comment: @Eliel did you find a work around for this ??

Comment: @Eliel I have the same problem? did you solved this problem?

Comment: @Berkay did you solved this problem?

Comment: @jsantos1991 nope, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution (work with NetBeans 8.0.2):

download the listed archives below from:

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/release72-au/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/extra/

- org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpc.nbm
- org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpc16.nbm
- org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxrpckit.nbm
- org-netbeans-modules-websvc-registry.nbm

Once you can start NetBeans without problems install as downloaded plugin (Tools>Plugins>Downloaded>Add Plugins...), its worked for me.
enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all files in these two folders:

```
C:\Users\Ghost\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\ 
C:\Users\Ghost\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.4\
```

And try to create a bug report in Netbeans's Bugzilla: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/

Comment: No, it doesnt work. When you delete those files netbeans is starting but plugin has gone.

Comment: Yes, it is the goal of this trick, is to make him start NetBeans, and after this to do an update to pass to netbeans 8.0.2 which is latest version.

Comment: The thing is, in the end you can't use JAX-RPC Plugin. When you install that plugin Netbeans doesn't open. When you clean those directories, plugin has gone. We tried with 8.0.2, 8.0.1, 8.0, 7.x. I guess it is about the plugin problems.

Comment: Even deleting these two folders, Netbeans 8 still will not run for me after installing some plugins. Time to rebuild it.

Comment: ok, after deleting these files I have to set up enviroment (servers and others settings) from scratch, wrr

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be pinned down to the directory:
NetBeans 8.0\platform\core
Where the libraries core.jar and org-openide-filesystems.jar are replaced with smaller versions from http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz.
Also libraries in NetBeans 8.0\platform\lib seem to be replaced.
Some libraries in NetBeans 8.0\platform\modules\ are also wrecked.
So the best way to restore your Netbeans is a reinstallation and download the NBMs separately as described by Relativo.

For Netbeans 8, this link can be used to download the NBMs:
http://deadlock.netbeans.org/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/extra/